# Point location in axis parallel rectangles

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I'm new in computational geometry and I have the following question:

Suppose Given $n$ disjoint axis parallel rectangles $R$ in plane. We want preprocess $R$ in $O(n\log n)$ with $O(n)$ space such that for each given point $q$  we must find a rectangle that contains $q$ in $O(log^2n)$. I have no any idea for solving this problem but i read [this link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2225/point-location-problem-in-polygon-in-repetitive-mode-for-a-simple-polygon?rq=1).

Comment: Why do you think it is solvable in those time bounds?  Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?